# Unexpected behavior with type-juggling in PHP

Tags: php

I know about type juggling in PHP, but I don't quite understand this logic. I'd expect 'foo2bar' as output, but the below one gives '1bar' as output.

```
<?php
    $x = 1;
    echo 'foo' . $x + 1 . 'bar'; // echoes '1bar'
?>
```

Where does the `'foo'` go? Can someone explain this?

Comment: In other words: `echo ((('foo' . $x) + 1) . 'bar');`

Comment: So, the concatenation operator evaluates first since it is left associative. ((('foo' . $x) + 1) . 'bar') becomes (('foo1' + 1)  . 'bar'), because of type-juggling it evaluates to (1 . 'bar') and echoes '1bar'.

Comment: 1. Both have the same precedence 2. Yes because of the left associative 3. yes at the end it's 1 and "bar"